# Best way to return the nth digit in a number?

Tags: javascript

I have a solution but it looks messy and was hoping there was a better way:

Write a function that returns the nth digit of a number

```js
/*
Write a function that returns the nth digit of a number
digitN(498, 1)  // 8
digitN(498, 10) // 9
digitN(498, 100) // 4
*/

function digitN(number, base){
  if(base === 1){
    return number % 10;
  }
  if(base === 10){
    return Math.floor((number % 100) / 10);
  }
  if(base === 100){
    return Math.floor((number % 1000) / 100);
  }
}

console.log(digitN(498, 100))
```

Comment: If you look closely at the relationship between `base` and the rest of the code… It's just `(number % (base * 10)) / base`…

Comment: I guess we can assume `number` is always a power of 10? If that's the case and you don't want to think about operations at all, there's also `+(""+num)[(base+"").length]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to do it with fewer operations and function calls.

```
function digitN(N, base) {
    return Math.floor(N / base % 10);
}
```

Or if you are a cool cat:

```
const digitN(N, base) => Math.floor(N / base % 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass position instead of `base * 10`, then simply convert number to string and act as with array:

```js
digitN(498, 1);  // 8
digitN(498, 2); // 9
digitN(498, 3); // 4

function digitN(number, position) {
  strNumber = '' + number;
  digit = strNumber[strNumber.length - position];

  console.log(digit);
  
  return digit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

```
function digitN(number, base){

    return Math.floor((number % (base * 10)) / base);

}
```

Comment: Or in ES6 `const digitN(n,b) => Math.floor((n % (b * 10)) / b`

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this...

```
function digitN(number, base){

    return Math.floor((number % (base * 10)) / base );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the value by `base` and get the integer value of the rest with ten.

```js
function digitN(number, base) {
    return Math.floor((number / base) % 10);
}

console.log(digitN(498, 1));   // 8
console.log(digitN(498, 10));  // 9
console.log(digitN(498, 100)); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheeky solution with converting it into a string:

```js
var num = ''+1492;

console.log(num[0])
console.log(num[1])
console.log(num[2])
console.log(num[3])
```

Comment: as in @Justinas' answer.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Left the snippet editor open and I didn't see their answer.